# How to publish a react app in any directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I have a react app which I may want to run from different directories possibly on multiple hosts.

> https://myhost.com/relative/path/1/index.html

> https://myhost.com/relative/path/2/index.html

> https://myhost2.com/relative/path/1/index.html

I notice when I click on a home link URL always shows

> https://myhost.com/home
> instead of
> https://myhost.com/relative/path/1/home

Is this expected behavior?

```
<Link to={`${this.settings.getClientBaseUrl()}home`}>Home</Link>
```

```
<Route exact path={`${this.settings.getClientBaseUrl()}`} element={<HomePage parent={this.parent} />} />
```

I am looking for a definitive way or explanation on how to have the URL look like

> https://myhost.com/relative/path/1/home

instead of

> https://myhost.com/home

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this.

1. Base Url

```
let baseUrl = window.location.pathname;
baseUrl = \`${baseUrl.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')}/\`; // get dir of filepath
```

If you put the output of build in https://example.com/path/to/script
baseUrl = '/path/to/script/';

2. Routes

```
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}`} element={<HomePage props={props} />} />
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}index.html`} element={<HomePage props={props} />} />
<Route exact path={`${baseUrl}home`} element={<HomePage props={props} />} />
```

3. Links

```
<Link to={`${baseUrl}home`}>Home</Link>
```

4. .htaccess goes into the same directory of the react index.html

```
# begin redirect to index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
# end redirect to index.html
```